# Proof that the $(\mathcal P (\mathbb N),\triangle)$ is an abelian group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, elementary-set-theory

I'm stuck trying to figure out how to prove that $(\mathcal P (\mathbb N) \space , \space \triangle)$ is an abelian group? I know the definition, but I'm confused how to incorporate the fact that I'm dealing with a powerset instead of just the integers or natural numbers, so I'm seeking help to understand how proofs on sets works.

Also, I'm using $\triangle$ to mean symmetric difference.

Comment: @Peter: $X$ is the identity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just check the axioms. Prove that symmetric difference is commutative (which is clear from its definition) and associative (which takes a little work). Prove that there’s an identity, i.e., a set $Z$ such that $Z\triangle A=A$ for all $A\in\wp(\Bbb N)$; there’s exactly one set that has that property, and it’s not hard to find. Finally, check that every $A\in\wp(\Bbb N)$ has an inverse. A **hint** for both of those last parts: what’s $A\triangle A$?

Comment: Not quite sure about the hint, but would the empty set work as an identity element? I believe that A $\triangle \space \emptyset$ = A, but I could be wrong

Comment: @Benzne_O: You’re right: $A\triangle\varnothing=(A\setminus\varnothing)\cup(\varnothing\setminus A)=A\cup\varnothing=A$ for all $A$. Thus, $\varnothing$ works just fine as the identity.

Comment: Alright thanks, this answer made the most sense to me.

Comment: @Benzne_O: You’re welcome. Feel free to ask for further clarification if you need it.

Answer (score 4):

Possibly the best approach is to note that if $A$ is an arbitrary set, and you associate to each element of $B \in \mathcal P ( A)$ its characteristic function
$$
\textbf{1}_{B} : {A} \to \mathbf{Z}_{2},
f(a) = \begin{cases} 1 & \text{if $a \in B$},\\ 0 & \text{if $a \notin B$,}\end{cases}
$$
then symmetric difference becomes (pointwise) sum of characteristic functions,
$$
\textbf{1}_{B} + \textbf{1}_{C} = \textbf{1}_{B \Delta C}
$$

Comment: This is the best, mainly when we verify the associativity.+1

Comment: I agree. On the other hand, associativity is also clear for the sets directly: Both $A \Delta (B \Delta C)$ and $(A \Delta B) \Delta C$ consist of those elements which belong to exactly one of the sets $A,B,C \subseteq X$.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg, absolutely, that is, those element that belong to *an odd number* ($1$ or $3$ here) of the sets $A, B, C$. Still I find instructive how a detour may reduce the problem to a standard, general argument.

Answer (score 0):

In fact $(\mathcal P (X) \space , \triangle)$ is a group for any $X$:

- closure is immediate since $\triangle : \mathcal P (X) \times \mathcal P (X) \to \mathcal P (X)$
- identity: $x \triangle \{\} = x$
- inverses: $x \triangle x = \{\}$ so everything is its own inverse.
- associativity: $(x \triangle y) \triangle z = x \triangle (y \triangle z)$ is obvious from a venn diagram.

and it's abelian because $\triangle$ is symmetric.

Comment: Sorry, but $x \triangle (X \setminus x) = X$

Comment: You want $x\triangle x=\varnothing$.